# Windows registry and installed software

Tags: c#, regex, vbscript, registry, sam

I am trying to make a script, that will give me a report of the software installed on a Windows machine.

Right now i am pulling the information from the registry uninstall folder, but there is a problem.

**I get two much info**

I am not interested in software like helpers, runtime, driverpacks and so on. The only thing that matters is software that could need a licens eg. Microsoft SQL server, MS Office, Adobe Photoshop and so on.

Is there a smart way of determining that or is it the hard way and sort through it via Regular exp?

Right now i have a VBScript that creates a txt file. Then i'm sorting through it in C#.

```
on error resume next 

Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network") 
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\a-frkjer\Desktop\" & strcomputer & ".txt", True) 

strKey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" 
strEntry1a = "DisplayName" 
strEntry1b = "QuietDisplayName"
strEntry1c = "Publisher" 

Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputer & _ 
 "/root/default:StdRegProv") 
objReg.EnumKey HKLM, strKey, arrSubkeys 

objTextFile.WriteLine ".::SECTION"

For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys 
  intRet1 = objReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, _ 
   strEntry1a, strValue1) 
  intRet1c = objReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, _ 
   strEntry1c, strValue1c) 
  If intRet1 <> 0 Then 
    objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, _ 
     strEntry1b, strValue1 
  End If 
  If strValue1 <> "" Then 
    objTextFile.WriteLine strValue1c & " " & strValue1 & " ¿ " & strcomputer & "¿" 
  End If 
Next 

strKey2 = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" 
strEntry2a = "DisplayName" 
strEntry2b = "QuietDisplayName" 
strEntry2c = "Publisher" 

Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputer & _ 
 "/root/default:StdRegProv") 
objReg.EnumKey HKLM, strKey2, arrSubkeys 

objTextFile.WriteLine ".::SECTION"

For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys 
  intRet2 = objReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, strKey2 & strSubkey, _ 
   strEntry2a, strValue2) 
  intRet2c = objReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, strKey2 & strSubkey, _ 
   strEntry2c, strValue2c) 
  If intRet2 <> 0 Then 
    objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey2 & strSubkey, _ 
     strEntry2b, strValue2 
  End If 
  If strValue2 <> "" Then 
        objTextFile.WriteLine strValue2c & " " & strValue2 & " ¿ " & strcomputer & "¿" 
  End If 
Next 

objTextFile.Close
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ignore keys with SystemComponent=1

Comment: I don't see any key with the name SystemComponent

Comment: its a value in the key for a {guid}